What does the "das" in "Was ist das" mean?
Are both the word that and article the written as das?
I have always thought das in Was ist das? only mean that, until today, I encountered the sentence Wo ist der?, der here means the, so it means Where is the?, right?
Extrapolating that, Was ist das? can mean What is that? or What is the?.
When someone points at das sofa (the sofa) and ask Was ist das?, are they asking What is that? or What is the? ?
Please help me understand this topic. Thank you.

User DonQuiKong made a good comment / question:
So a better translation of "Wo ist der?" would be "Where is he/it?"? Or even also "Where is that (masculine thing)?" And "Wo ist das?" would also be "Where is that (neutrum thing)?"?

German definite articles, relative pronouns and demonstrative pronouns all have the same forms, so you have to distinguish them by context. When such a word does not precede a noun, it's clearly not an article.

The same word can mean two different things in German. Obviously German is the only language with this feature, given how much some people here are confused by this. I guess it was added to the language on purpose, just to confuse learners.

In general this question highlights one of the main shortcomings of the traditional translation based approach to language learning: it can be hard to remember that your new language isn’t just a gloss on your primary language—it’s a language in its own right. And just as in your primary language words have multiple senses, so too in your new language, but there’s not going to be a 1-1 mapping between the two languages. Or to put it another way, your new language is a language to be learned with its own unique grammar and vocab. It’s not an encoding of your primary language to be decoded.

English that can be both a determiner (i.e. combined with a noun) and a pronoun (i.e. stand in place of a noun), whereas the functions exclusively as a determiner.

Did you see that magnificent building / the magnificent building over there? (determiner)
Did you see that? (pronoun)

German determiners der, das, die (masculine, neuter, feminine) are mostly homophonous to the pronouns der, das, die.

Hast du das tolle Gebäude gesehen? (determiner)
Hast du das gesehen? (pronoun)
Hast du den großen Saal gesehen? (determiner)
Hast du den gesehen? (pronoun)
Hast du die neue Haltestelle gesehen? (determiner)
Hast du die gesehen? (pronoun)

The forms in the dative plural are distinct, though.

Diese Gebäude ähneln den anderen (Gebäuden). (determiner)
Diese Gebäude ähneln denen. (pronoun)

In was ist das?, there is no noun. Therefore, das is a pronoun, not a determiner. Note that what is the? is ungrammatical in English; the determiner cannot stand alone, without a noun.
Examples in all three genders:

Wo ist das Kleid? (determiner)
Wo ist das? (pronoun)
Wo ist der Mantel? (determiner)
Wo ist der? (pronoun)
Wo ist die Jacke? (determiner)
Wo ist die? (pronoun)


So a better translation of "Wo ist der?" would be "Where is he/it?"? Or even also "Where is that (masculine thing)?" And "Wo ist das?" would also be "Where is that (neutrum thing)?"?

"Where is he/it?" would be "Wo ist er?"

Das is a demonstrative pronoun here, it could be replaced by dies. The sentence is probably uttered when pointing to something.
